# Error when executing "cabal install hoogle"

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

When I run `cabal install hoogle`, I get the following:

```
setup: The program happy version >=1.17 is required but it could not be found
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install
haskell-src-exts-1.13.3 failed during the configure step the exeption is ExitFailure 1

$ghc -V
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.1
```

How to fix such a problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `cabal install hoogle`, run `cabal install alex happy && cabal install hoogle`.

Many packages on hackage require `alex` and `happy`, so it is good idea to install them after `cabal update`.

Answer (score 2):

I had lot's of trouble installing hoogle locally. Adding the cabal binary directory, ~/.cabal/bin to my PATH with

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.cabal/bin
```

ended up essentially fixing my problem. After that, just follow the errors and install anything that cabal barks about missing, including alex and happy.